# The k-shortest paths between a pair of vertices with negative edges

Tags: graph, graph-theory

I'm trying to the find the k-shortest paths between a pair of vertices in a directed graph, with negative weights allowed. As far I know, Eppstein's algorithm and Yen's algorithm only work with positive weights.

I know bellman-ford can be used to find the shorest path with with negative edges but I'm also trying to find the second shortest, third shortest, etc.

Comment: One implementation could be that, you use bellman ford to find the shortest path, then remove the path traversed during the first pass, so now when you run the algorithm again, you will get the second shortest path. Hope this helps.

Comment: @zenwraight how do I remove a path without effecting the graph?